# Call to a member function rollback() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I run a localhost XAMPP server at my office for testing purposes. I am traveling and decided I'd get some work done on my laptop so I installed a new version of XAMPP on my laptop, copied my files over but for some reason, I get non-stop errors on my laptop version where I don't get a single on my desktop.

One of the big ones is a simple log in page for one of my sites.

every time I try and run the code, I get the following error:

> Call to a member function rollback()
>   on a non-object

My code is:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
        header('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
        die();
    }   

    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB', 'USER', 'PW');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->beginTransaction();

        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT user, pw FROM table WHERE user=? AND pw=?");
        $sql->execute(array($_POST['user'], $_POST['pw']));
        $foundrows = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();

        $rows = $sql->fetchAll();

        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $username = $row[0];
            $pw = $row[1];
        }

        $db->commit();
        $db->NULL;
    }

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $db->rollback();
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }


    if ($foundrows == 1) {

        (store stuff and exit to Page A)

    } else {

        (create error and return to login page)

    }
?>
```

As I said before, this runs without issue on my desktop (and several live sites i use elsewhere). What the H is going on?

Note: I thought it may be different configurations of my PHP file but i copied over the php.ini file from my desktop and still no luck...

Comment: What is the output of "echo $e->getMessage();"? Maybe you have to move it one line up the get it, before the script terminates.

Comment: @JochenJung - there is no output, also, moving up would do nothing. the function is cauasing an issue @ $db->rollback();

Comment: Sure moving up, could give you annother message. Have you tried? For the try block failes due to your error. $db beeing not defined (the error message you see now) is just a result of this. But now you won't see the $e->getMessage(), cause the script terminates in the line before.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is indicating that `$db->rollback()` is failing, because `$db` has not been defined.  Let's have a look at a snippet of your code:

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB', 'USER', 'PW');
    [snip]
}

catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $db->rollback();
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

I think your code isn't even getting past the first statement in the `catch` block, i.e. an exception is being thrown in the `PDO` constructor.  To test this, move `echo $e->getMessage;` above `$db->rollback()`, or do the rollback conditionally:

```
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    if ($db) {
        $db->rollback();
    }
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

To fix this more generally, please check your database settings closely -- perhaps there has been an error moving from one server to another?